# Why isn't my Javascript Switch Case working?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

When using the JSfiddle interpreter, the button and input field appear in the 'result' box, however there doesn't seem to be any response to the script. I tried other interpreters, such as that of the W3School, and while it does give me an indication that the function is in fact being called, the result seems to only be the default case, and even that only appears for a fraction of a second before the entire field along with the button and input disappear (Worth noting the text I input does not appear in the paragraph, and 'fruitT' seems to be ignored -- so most likely there is an issue with the passing of info between the input field, the button and the function.)

The logic seems pretty straightforward to me and I've looked at other examples -- however I am new to JS so I've potentially overlooked some syntax. Hoping somebody could give me a push in the right direction. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <form action="#">
        <input id="fruit">
            <button onclick="myFunc('fruit')">Enter</button>
    </form>
        <p id="here"></p>

<script>
function myFunc(fruitT){
  switch (fruitT){
   case "Oranges":
       document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = ("Oranges are $0.59 a pound.");
      break;
   case "Apples":
       document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = ("Apples are $0.32 a pound.<br>");
      break;
   default:
      document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = ("Sorry, we are out of " + fruitT + ".<br>");
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no need for using switch() on 1:1 conversions, a LookUpTable works perfectly: document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = {Oranges: "Oranges are $0.59 a pound.",Apples:"Apples are $0.32 a pound.<br>"}[fruitT]||("Sorry, we are out of " + fruitT + ".<br>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button inside a form submits the form, as it's default type is submit, reloading the page.
You probably also want to pass the inputs value to the function, not just the string `'fruit'`

change this line

```
<button onclick="myFunc('fruit')">Enter</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunc(document.getElementById('fruit').value)">Enter</button>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/hvR6v/1/)

Comment: d'oh. Maybe it's time for me to get outside for a little bit. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="myFunc('fruit')">Enter</button>
```

Passes the string "fruit" to your function, which would then hit default.

```
<button onclick="myFunc(fruit)">Enter</button>
```

Would run the function with the variable fruit, if it exists.